# Basic Logic: True Premises, False Conclusion?

Tags: logic

Is possible to have a false conclusion given that all its premises are true?

Comment: NO. [Valid argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)) means that "it impossible for the premises to be true and the conclusion nevertheless to be false."

Comment: You have remove the "valid" requirement: now an "argument" is a collection of sentences whatever. So, you can do whatever you want...

Comment: If you have an uncountable number of premises, you *might* be able to conjure up some sort of Axiom of Choice weirdness. In that case, the conclusion would be unprovable, not false.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible for an argument to have a false conclusion and also all true premises. An example is: Today is a weekday or a weekend, so you live on Mars. However, this situation is not possible when the argument is logically valid. Indeed, that is the definition of logical validity: that this situation is impossible.